# Generate code or events when drag-drop a custom control from the toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, custom-controls, windows-forms-designer

I'm creating a custom control (e.g custom LookUpEdit) and I'm wondering if I can generate code (e.g EditValueChanged event in form.cs file or some rows of code e.g in Form_Load event) automatically while I drag and drop this control inside a form designer, giving this way to any developer the opportunity to easily see and extend this code if he/she wants.

My question is: How to generate code or events automatically in a form (form.cs) when you drag-drop a custom control from the toolbox at design time?

Comment: Your custom control needs to expose public (custom) events, so anyone that needs them can subscribe to these events as usual. I don't see why you should *preemptively* generate code (except what will already be automatically generated in designer.cs).

Comment: Can you share an example of such event which should be generated when the component drops on the form? (A real scenario.)

Comment: If he/she wants to extend this code, then he/she will simply subscribe to these events, as they would normaly do. Now they are stuck with empty events they have to remove it they dont want to extend. Sounds like a strange idea

Comment: For example, i have created a custom combobox for Language selection with two items (e.g English, Spanish). In my  custom control i have code at EditValueChanged event to change the CurrentCultureUI based on user selected item. If any developer wants to use my control in any application, I would ideally have the code ready in form.cs file to extend it if he wants to add more languages.

Comment: You should provide means to extend these *property values* using the PropertyGrid, since this is the usual way. If I want a DataGridView, I drop it on the Form then I add Columns and eventually Rows using its custom interface. Unless you're trying to avoid smarttags and/or building a custom designer :)

Answer (score 1):

Some times you may want to generate some code when dropping a component on form. For example, you can see a similar behavior when you drag a data source from data source window and drop it on form.

The behavior is more common for extensions and add-ins, but you can implement such behavior for your component when dropping from toolbox as well.

The key points in the answer are:

- Creating a new designer for the control by deriving from [`ControlDesigner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8)
- Creating the event handler using [`IEventBindingService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.ieventbindingservice?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8)
- Adding code to the body of the event handler using [`CodeTypeDeclaration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.codetypedeclaration?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) service.

**Example**

I've created a `MyControl` control in this example. When you drop an instance of the control on the form, the designer will generate the following code for its `Click` event:

```
private void myControl1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hi!");

}
```

Here is the code of `MyControl` and `MyControlDesigner`. You may want to add null checking to the code.

```
using System.CodeDom;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

[Designer(typeof(MyControlDesigner))]
public partial class MyControl : Control
{
}

public class MyControlDesigner : ControlDesigner
{
    public override void InitializeNewComponent(IDictionary defaultValues)
    {
        base.InitializeNewComponent(defaultValues);
        var component = this.Component;
        var eventBindingService = (IEventBindingService)this.GetService(
            typeof(IEventBindingService));
        var componentChangeService = (IComponentChangeService)this.GetService(
            typeof(IComponentChangeService));
        var designerHostService = (IDesignerHost)GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost));
        var uiService = (IUIService)GetService(typeof(IUIService));
        var designerTransaction = (DesignerTransaction)null;
        try
        {
            designerTransaction = designerHostService.CreateTransaction();
            var e = TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(component)["Click"];
            if (e != null)
            {
                var methodName = eventBindingService.CreateUniqueMethodName(component, e);
                var eventProperty = eventBindingService.GetEventProperty(e);
                if (eventProperty.GetValue(component) == null)
                {
                    eventProperty.SetValue(component, methodName);
                    var code = this.GetService(typeof(CodeTypeDeclaration))
                        as CodeTypeDeclaration;
                    CodeMemberMethod method = null;
                    var member = code.Members.Cast<CodeTypeMember>()
                        .Where(x => x.Name == methodName).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (member != null)
                    {
                        method = (CodeMemberMethod)member;
                        method.Statements.Add(
                            new CodeSnippetStatement("MessageBox.Show(\"Hi!\");"));
                    }
                    componentChangeService.OnComponentChanged(component,
                        eventProperty, null, null);
                    eventBindingService.ShowCode(component, e);
                }
            }
            designerTransaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            if (designerTransaction != null)
                designerTransaction.Cancel();
            uiService.ShowError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tested the solution and it works properly. Let me know if you have any problem testing the solution.