# Generate custom C# code in Form.cs while dropping user control in Form1.cs at design time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a user control that I can drag and drop in the Form1.cs[Design] mode. The designer will auto-generate code for this user control in the Form1.Designer.cs

What I would like to get aswell is: at the moment I am adding the user control to the form by dragging I wont to have code generated in my Form.cs that is pointing to the properties and controls on that user control.

Example of user control:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string TextInTextBox
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
        set { textBox1.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

So now when I drag it on the form in the Form1.cs[Design]. I won't part of code like this to be generated in my Form1.cs:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddText();
    }

    // this code below to be auto-generated
    private void AddText()
    {
        userControl11.TextInTextBox = "";
    }
}
```

I think I should be looking for something like inheritance or interface but I would like this to happen for each instance of that user control.
If someone could point me direction what to look for it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried so far.  That way we can better help you.

Comment: I built interface and User control1 is inheriting that interface. But then I have to assign all the methods from that interface in the UserControl1.cs. And that is not what I want. I want these methods from the interface to show up for each instance of the UserControl1 in Form1.cs so the user knows he has to provide logic to fill the exposed properties for each instance of that UserControl1. I obviously search ed for it but I think i am asking the wrong question. All I need is a hint.

Comment: You can [Generate code or events when drag-drop a custom control from the toolbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54243900/3110834), but for setting a property, it's not a good idea. For setting a property you should use standard mechanisms like creating toolbox item or customizing the designer.

Comment: If it's just about setting a property, then it's enough to set some initial value for it. It will be serialized by designer. For example if you have this property `public string MyTextProperty { get; set; } = "SomeText";` in `UserControl`, then when you drop an instance of your control on form this code `this.myUserControl1.MyTextProperty = "SomeText";` will be generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you don't need to generate code manually when you want to assign a property when dropping a control from toolbox, for example you can easily do this:

```
public MyUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyTextProperty = "Something";
}
```

And it will be serialized automatically.

But there are more options for more advanced requirements.if you know the options that you have, you may choose based on your requirement. Here is some options:

- Assign some value in constructor or to the property
- Assign value to properties using `ToolboxItem`, it will overwrite the value which you assign in constructor.
- Generate some code for `Load` event of form and initialize property there. It's useful for complex code generations, for example when you drop a data source it will generate some code to load data and add to load event of form.

Assuming you have assigned `Something` to `MyTextProperty` in constructor, then when you drop the control in form, here is what will be generated in designer.cs:

```
this.myUserControl1.MyTextProperty = "Something";
```

If you use the `ToolboxItem` solution to assign `Something else` to the property, the result in designer.cs file will be:

```
this.myUserControl1.MyTextProperty = "Something else";
```

And if you decide to use third option and generate event handler code, the result in designer.cs file will be:

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
```

and the result in cs file will be:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myUserControl1.MyTextProperty = "Even something else!";
}
```

**Example**

Here is a full code of `MyUserControl`, `MyUserControlToolboxItem` and `MyUserControlDesigner`. You can comment `Designer` and/or `ToolboxItem` attributes and close all designers and clean and rebuild the solution and drop an instance of the control on the form to see how it works.

```
using System.CodeDom;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

[Designer(typeof(MyUserControlDesigner))]
[ToolboxItem(typeof(MyUserControlToolBoxItem))]
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string MyTextProperty { get; set; } = "Something";
}

public class MyUserControlToolBoxItem : ToolboxItem
{
    protected override IComponent[] CreateComponentsCore(IDesignerHost host)
    {
        IComponent[] componentsCore = base.CreateComponentsCore(host);
        if (componentsCore != null && componentsCore.Length > 0
            && componentsCore[0] is MyUserControl)
            (componentsCore[0] as MyUserControl)
                .MyTextProperty = "Something else"; ;
        return componentsCore;
    }
}

public class MyUserControlDesigner : ControlDesigner
{
    public override void InitializeNewComponent(IDictionary defaultValues)
    {
        base.InitializeNewComponent(defaultValues);
        var component = Control;
        var eventBindingService = (IEventBindingService)this.GetService(
            typeof(IEventBindingService));
        var componentChangeService = (IComponentChangeService)this.GetService(
            typeof(IComponentChangeService));
        var designerHostService = (IDesignerHost)GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost));
        var rootComponent = designerHostService.RootComponent;
        var uiService = (IUIService)GetService(typeof(IUIService));
        var designerTransaction = (DesignerTransaction)null;
        try
        {
            designerTransaction = designerHostService.CreateTransaction();
            var e = TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(rootComponent)["Load"];
            if (e != null)
            {
                var methodName = "";
                var eventProperty = eventBindingService.GetEventProperty(e);
                if (eventProperty.GetValue(rootComponent) == null)
                {
                    methodName = eventBindingService
                        .CreateUniqueMethodName(rootComponent, e);
                    eventProperty.SetValue(rootComponent, methodName);
                }
                else
                    methodName = (string)eventProperty.GetValue(rootComponent);
                var code = this.GetService(typeof(CodeTypeDeclaration))
                        as CodeTypeDeclaration;
                CodeMemberMethod method = null;
                var member = code.Members.Cast<CodeTypeMember>()
                    .Where(x => x.Name == methodName).FirstOrDefault();
                if (member != null)
                {
                    method = (CodeMemberMethod)member;
                    method.Statements.Add(
                        new CodeSnippetStatement($"{Control.Name}" +
                        $".MyTextProperty = \"Even something else!\";"));
                }
                componentChangeService.OnComponentChanged(rootComponent,
                    eventProperty, null, null);
                eventBindingService.ShowCode(rootComponent, e);
            }
            designerTransaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            if (designerTransaction != null)
                designerTransaction.Cancel();
            uiService.ShowError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reza Aghaei thank you very much. That is exactly what I was looking for. You are a star. Sorry for the late reply but hade another task and needed to learn the Luhn algorithm.

Comment: You're welcome @LechKrawczyk :) To make sure that you get all points in the answer, you can comment `Designer` and/or `ToolboxItem` attributes and close all designers and clean and rebuild the solution and drop an instance of the control on the form and see the generated code to see how it works.